# how do i use a jwt token?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

im new to this and spent all my time trying to figure out how to build a way to generate jwt tokens - given the understanding that you need them for user 'signed in' status.

i used fastapi, and when i login/register using my app, i now get a token, and 'bearer':

```
{access_token: 'super long string', token_type: 'bearer'}
```

how do i use this to show another view/page/component?  what is the process? is there some sort of decoder? all the videos/tutorials i see are focused on how to get it using node or other means, but i already have it...

Comment: well, seeing as JWTs are authenticated using a server (like NodeJS), you can't really sort this out without one. try rephrasing the question to be a little more clear about what it is you want specifically.

Comment: @Imagifight  have a postgres server running in a container, with a fastapi container between the nextjs app and the postgres server...i just dont understand how the 'state' is supposed to change now

Comment: If you got a token from the API, you now have to add it to the `Authorization` HTTP header every time you make a request for some resource on the API. It's not really used to show other views/pages since all those things are frontend things, but it can restrict or allow you to fetch certain data from the API.

Comment: @ShamPooSham this is exactly the part i am not understanding...are there any resources for how to add it to Authorization? im a bit confused about where i set my limits for this token etc

Comment: tokens are meant for the user to authorize themselves for `accessing` or `updating` a resource

Comment: @ShamPooSham the only solutions i could figure out is just conditionally rendering based on if i get a response back...but im sure there is more to this

Comment: @avnav99 I'm not sure about Next.js, but usually the token is stored in localStorage when you recieve it, and then when you make a new request to the API, you add it to the HTTP Header called `Authorization`. It's only useful if you do AJAX calls, for example through the `fetch()` function where you can set the header in the second argument.

Comment: You could also send the token in a cookie. Then you can use it for normal requests, too. What does the backend expect and what does it respond?

Comment: @jabaa i structured this app to have 3 states and thereby 3 different 'views' or parent renderings...so i'd like to make it so that the state switches when this token is received, i.e. the person is now logged in

Comment: ShamPooSham already described it. Usually you store the token in localStorage. The frontend assumes that the user is logged in as long there is a token in the storage. The token is sent with every request and removed from storage when the server responds with status 401.

Comment: @jabaa i will try that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to pass this token in your headers in order to access the API.
Consider the following Axios js example:

```
var axios = require('axios');

var config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: `http://${<your_api_url>}/v1/users/`,
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': `${<token_type>} ${<access_token>}`
  }
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did:

#### Step 1 - set the state for my parent page:

```
  const [jwtholder, setJwtHolder] = useState('non-bearer')
  const [jwttoken, setJwtToken] = useState('');

  const mainprops = {
    // session,
    jwtholder,
    setJwtHolder,
    jwttoken,
    setJwtToken,
    visitorType,
    setVisitorType
  };
```

#### Step 2 - adjust the conditional rendering in the parent page, and pass the states:

```
  else if (jwtholder=='bearer' && visitorType =='buyside') {
    return(
      <div>
        <Buyside {...mainprops}/>
      </div>
    )}
  else if (jwtholder=='bearer' && visitorType =='sellside') {
    return(
      <div>
        <Sellside {...mainprops}/>
      </div>
    )}
  };
```

#### Step 3 - pass those main props through the formik component:

```
        onSubmit={ (values, {setSubmitting, resetForm} ) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                _handleLogin({mainprops, values});
                resetForm();
                setSubmitting(false);
        }, 1000)
        }}
```

#### Step 4 - use the handler to pass the request, and adjust the parent state:

```
export default async function _handleSubmit(mainprops,creds) {        
        if (creds.api == 'register'){
        var publish_api = 'http://localhost:8007/register/'; //fastapi
        }
        else if (creds.api =='login') {publish_api = 'http://localhost:8007/login/';}//fastapi

        const requestOptions = {
                        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
                        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
                        cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
                        credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
                        headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(creds.Data)
                };
        //wait for the promise to come back:
        let response = await fetch(publish_api, requestOptions);
        let authorization = await response.json()
        mainprops.setJwtHolder(authorization.token_type);
        mainprops.setJwtToken(authorization.access_token);
        mainprops.setVisitorType('buyside')
        // publish parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
        }
```

Obviously there are a few components in between.

When I make any future requests to other APIs, I'll include that `jwttoken` in the header.  (I'm not sure why I repeat the word token here.)

AND add a conditional for a 401 response to change the `jwtholder` state.